# Write answers in the same line using package mcexam

Tags: lists, examdesign, mcexam

To write a multiple questions exam, I'm currently using the [mcexam](https://mirror.hmc.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/mcexam/mcexam.pdf) package, which allows to randomize both the questions and the answers. I need to print the answers in one single line, but in the package documentation it isn't stated if this is possible. By default, the output is a numerical list which appears like the one obtained with the enumitem package.
There is a way to print answers in a single line?
Thank you!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[output=exam, numberofversions=8, version=3, randomizequestions=true,randomizeanswers=true]{mcexam}%

 \usepackage[top=10mm,bottom=10mm,inner=10mm,outer=10mm, marginparwidth=20mm, marginparsep=4mm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\setlist[setmcquestions]{label=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}.
,ref=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}
14
,itemsep=.5\baselineskip
,topsep=.5\baselineskip         }
\setlist[setmcanswerslist]{label=\mcanswerlabelfmt{*}
,noitemsep}
\setlist[setmcquestioninfo]{before=\footnotesize\sffamily}

\begin{mcquestions}
\question Question 1:
\begin{mcanswerslist}
\answer first answer
\answer second ansewr
\answer third answer
\answer fourth answer
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added the MWE

Comment: You're missing an `\end{mcquestions}` there.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I made a mistake while cutting the other answers

Comment: It is stated in the package documentation how to put all answers in a single line.

Comment: Can you tell me where you found it? I can't manage to find a command to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is listed in the package documentation (as of writing this in
subsection 2.2.). The second method I just tested out of curiosity and it worked
quite well for short answers.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  output=exam,
  numberofversions=8,
  version=3,
  randomizequestions=true,
  randomizeanswers=true]{mcexam}%

\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\setlist[setmcquestions]{label=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}.
,ref=\mcquestionlabelfmt{*}
14
,itemsep=.5\baselineskip
,topsep=.5\baselineskip         }
\setlist[setmcanswerslist]{label=\mcanswerlabelfmt{*}
,noitemsep}
\setlist[setmcquestioninfo]{before=\footnotesize\sffamily}

\begin{mcquestions}
\question Question 1:
\begin{mcanswers}
  \begin{tabular}
    {c@{\hskip\tabcolsep}*3{c@{\hskip3\tabcolsep}c@{\hskip\tabcolsep}}c}
    \answernum{1}&\answer{1}{first answer}  &
    \answernum{2}&\answer{2}{second answer} &
    \answernum{3}&\answer{3}{third answer}  &
    \answernum{4}&\answer{4}{fourth answer}
  \end{tabular}
\end{mcanswers}
\end{mcquestions}

\begin{mcquestions}
\question Question 1:
\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{mcanswerslist}
\answer one
\answer two
\answer three
\answer four
\end{mcanswerslist}
\end{multicols}
\end{mcquestions}

\end{document}
```

Results: [image]